# Mongoose: save() is not a function when using find() and atributing value to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

This is the basic structure of the Schema I am working with using mongoose:

```js
  const User = {
    uid: {
      type: String
    },
    routes: {
      type: Array
    }
   }
```

In my application there is a POST to <kbd>/route</kbd>, in which **uid** and a new **route** are provided as "body parameters". In order to add to the *routes* array, I wrote a code similar to this (the only diference is that I check if the route already exists):

```js
  var user = await User.find({uid: uid}) // user is found, as expected
  user[0].routes.push(route //parameter)  
  user.save()
```

When a POST request is made, though, it throws an error:

> TypeError: user.save is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` in your code is an array of documents

so you'll have mongo documents inside that array

you can't do `array.save`, you've to do `document.save`

`await user[0].save()`

```
var user = await User.find({uid: uid}) // user is found, as expected
if (user && user.length) {
    user[0].routes.push(route //parameter)  
    await user[0].save(); // save the 1st element of the object
}
```

if your query returns only 1 record better use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

```
var user = await User.findOne({uid: uid}) // user is found, as expected
if (user) {
    user.routes.push(route //parameter)  
    await user.save(); // save the 1st element of the object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to find only one specific user you should use `findOne` function instead

```
User.findOne({uid: uid})
.then(
    (user) => {
        user[0].routes.push(route //parameter);
        user.save();
    },
    (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [bulkSave()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkSave) can be what you're looking for:

```
  var user = await User.find({uid: uid}
  enter code user[0].routes.push(route //parameter)  
  await User.bulkSave(user)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31443362)